# fielding 2d vectors c++ difficulties

Tags: c++

I have 2d vector private attribute in c++ class defined like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<unsigned int> > m_voisins;
```

And a function that fills it with data like this:

```
template<typename N>
void Graphe<N>::initialiseVoisins(size_t n)
{
    m_voisins.resize(n);
    vector <unsigned int> voisins;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(unsigned int u=0; u<n; ++u)
        {
            if(m_matriceAdj[i][u]!=numeric_limits<N>::max() && u!=i)
            {
                voisins.push_back(u);
            }
        }
        m_voisins.push_back(voisins);
        voisins.clear();
    }
}
```

I can guarantee that the if statement in the middle is not the problem. I have tried without it and still the same result. 
The problem is that it seems that every time I call:

```
m_voisins[some_valid_index].size()
```

I get the result 0.

I would love to know why that is? 
The implementation seems fine to me, hopefully I am wrong hehe. Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? When and where do you check the matrices? How can you guarantee the `if` statement and function calling? Have you tried stepping through the function in a debugger?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it should be correct without `[i]`.

Comment: @timrau Well, you're right. Then the `resize(n)` is the problem. My correction should have looked like `m_voisins[i] = voisins;`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg. I tried it without removing the if statement and it still gave me the same thing. That same if statement is used in many places in my code and it works fine. I'll try the debugger though.

Comment: _"I can guarantee that the if statement in the middle is not the problem"_ Then prove it by abstracting it out of your example so that it does not (a) distract us, and (b) cause doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
m_voisins.resize(n);
```

Whoops! Now you're going to end up with `n*2` elements, and the first half of them (the ones you're inspecting) have nothing in them.

I'm sure you meant:

```
m_voisins.reserve(n);
```

This pre-allocates memory so that the `push_back`s are as fast as possible, without actually adding any logical elements.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have `m_voisins.resize(n);` in the beginning, which just creates `n` empty vectors in the beginning of `m_voisins`.

Either remove the `m_voisins.resize(n);`, or use `m_voisins[i] = voisins;` instead of `push_back()`.

Comment: Or, write `reserve` instead of `resize` and keep the `push_back` ... which is what I'd do.